# How to read a value from API in flutter but it is not a json

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, flutter

My API returns just "pending" as the output when called.

I use the future function to call the API.

```
 Future getOtp(rollNumber, phoneNumber, schoolName) async {

    Response response = await post(genOtpUrl, body: {
      "rollNumber" : rollNumber,
      "phNumber": phoneNumber,
      "schoolName" : schoolName
    });
    print(response.body);
    var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return result;

  }
```

Here it prints 'pending to the console' but the return statement just return Future I want to access the data but it is not a JSON how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"pending' is a String so you have to return a String.

```
Future<String> getOtp(rollNumber, phoneNumber, schoolName) async {
    Response response = await post(genOtpUrl, body: {
      "rollNumber" : rollNumber,
      "phNumber": phoneNumber,
      "schoolName" : schoolName
    });
    print(response.body);
    var result = response.body;
    return result;
  }
```

To access the string you can do the following

```
callOtp() async{
   String otpResult = await getOtp(rollNumber, phoneNumber, schoolName);
   print(otpResult);
}
```